# border radius dissapears after a second

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website currently and I try to make the profile picture have a border-radius so it is round. This works in first instance, but after 1 second it pops back to a square.

The profile picture also flips around when hovered.

Any solutions?

```css
.border
{
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.roundedImage {
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.8s;

}

.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000;
 z-index:3;
}
 
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}


.flipper {
 transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 
}


.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}


.front {
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="border">

<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">

<div class="roundedImage">

<div class="flipper">

<div class="front">
<div style="background: url(Images/L2351108.jpg); height:200px; background-size: cover;"></div>
</div>

<div class="back">
<div style="background:url(Images/L2351070.jpg); height:200px; background-size:cover;"</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `border` attributes everywhere in you postet css (you don't need them) and add

```
.front div, .back div {
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

to your css. That works for me.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yupy8z1x/)